# Handle 2 routes to the same destination simultaneously

Tags: ip, route, iproute

I setup on my machine 2 different routes on 2 different interfaces to reach a single destination.

When I ping a machine on that destination network, the packet go through the route with the highest priority. Is there a way to send the packet to every route that reach that destination ?

I'm using ROS2 which automatically discard duplicated message. The idea is to have 2 ways to communicate with our cloud for reliability purpose. One via direct 4G on `eth1` and the other one via a ground-node (ip-radio) on `eth0` that is connected via Ethernet. The idea is to actually send messages to those 2 interfaces in the same time. Ideally, I need to read from them also at the same time.

Comment: What is your final purpose ? Because the packets will arrived duplicated at destination which is a total non-sense ...

Comment: I edited the question and added a bit of background. Let me know if you need any more information. I was thinking about link bonding, could it be a way of solving that problem ?

Comment: [binarym](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/358836/binarym) any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean you need to "read from them at the same time"?  You want your applications to receive the messages twice?

Comment: [Philip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20140/philip-couling) As I said, I'm working with ROS2 both on my device and on my server. ROS2 automatically discard duplicate message. The idea is to have 2 ways of communication, the fastest one will be the preferred one without having to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any particular experience with ROS2, but for any normal Linux distro, you could use `iptables` or `nftables` to duplicate the traffic. Of cause, you will need to be able to handle the duplicate packets at the receiving end.

For both, you set up the default route through either one of the interfaces, and then you do something like this

```
nft add rule mangle prerouting dup to $secondaryGatewayIP
```

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway $secondaryGatewayIP
```

These rule will duplicate all traffic, which might not be what you want. You can always use more restrictive filters to limit duplication to only traffic going to your servers

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'll check that ! Will let you know !